# Is it possible to send an html email with PHP that inludes CSS decoration without using MIME?

Tags: php, css, email

I need to send an email with PHP that is decorated with CSS. My code as of right now works just fine for sending an html email. But, I can't seem to find out how to decorate it.

Here is my code:

```
//Message
    $message =  "<html>
                    <head>
                        <style type='text/css'>
                            #show {border:solid 1px #c4c4c4; background-color:#f0f0f0; width:400px;}
                            #red {color:#F02311}
                            #header {font-size:14px}
                            p {color:#090127}
                        </style>
                        <title>
                            Red-line
                        </title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <div id='show'>
                            <a id='red' href='http://www.thered-line.com'>The Red-line</a>
                        </div>

                        <p>
                            Hi $first_name, 
                        </p> 

                        <p>
                            Your Red-line account is almost complete. To finish, go to <a href='www.thered-line.com'>The Red-line</a> and enter your eight digit confirmation code.
                        </p> 

                        <p>
                            Your confirmation code is: <b>$code</b>
                        </p> 

                        <p>
                            Sincerely,
                        </p> <br />

                        <p>
                            The Red-line Operator
                        </p> 
                    </body>
                </html>";
```

Comment: Generally speaking, you should not use a `<style>` tag to style e-mails : you should include styles directly into the HTML, using the `style="..."` attribute.

Comment: @Pascal MARTIN: Interesting, but why's that?

Comment: What's wrong with using style tags?

Comment: From what I've heard, mail clients *(both software are webmails)* tend to have difficulties with styles that are not inlined.

Comment: If you use style tags, they generally get ignored in emails because email readers generally only support inline styles. A nice tool to do the job automatically can be found here: http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/

Comment: Also, if you use style tags, asside from it not working in many mail clients, it's possible that many common tag class names (logo, contact_info, etc) used in emails will get messed up in responses and forwards due to other people using the same class name in their signatures and whatnot. while a long shot, I have seen it happen.

Comment: The reason why css definitions inside style tags are ignored in web mail clients (e.g. gmail, yahoo mail) is, your css definitions, which are not inlined, can possibly corrupt/change their page layout.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the PHP libraries, but when I created mail with .Net I never included elements like `<head>` or `<body>`.  I don't think html mail messages are designed to be complete Html documents.

I would recommend that you included your `<style>` element, then go right into your content like this:

```
<style type='text/css'>
        #show {border:solid 1px #c4c4c4; background-color:#f0f0f0; width:400px;}
        #red {color:#F02311}
        #header {font-size:14px}
        p {color:#090127}
</style>    
<div id='show'>
       <a id='red' href='http://www.thered-line.com'>The Red-line</a>
</div>

 <p>
      Hi $first_name, 
 </p> 

 <p>
      Your Red-line account is almost complete. To finish, go to <a href='www.thered-line.com'>The Red-line</a> and enter your eight digit confirmation code.
 </p> 

 <p>
       Your confirmation code is: <b>$code</b>
 </p> 

 <p>
       Sincerely,
 </p> <br />

 <p>
       The Red-line Operator
 </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking a look into http://www.email-standards.org/ .
Several major webmail-clients remove or modify a bunch of important html elements - including <style ...>.

Inline-styles prevent your mailing from getting stripped off style completly.
From the mentioned page you can propably assemble your own set of supported /needed style attributes.